# How to get all the relations/neighbors of each tuple value from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

I am trying to get all the neighbors/pair of each tuple value from list of tuples.

input:

```
test_list = [(1, 'the'), (1, 'is'), (2, 'best'), (3, 'for'),(1, 'is'), (4, 'CS'), (2,'is'), ('is',3)]
```

desired output:

```
 {1: {'the','is'}, 2: {'best','is'}, 3: {'for','is'}, 4: {'CS'}, the: {1}, is: {1,2,3}, best: {2}, for: {3}, CS: {4}}
```

Comment: it should be test_list = [(1, 'the'), (1, 'is'), (2, 'best'), (3, 'for'),(1, 'is'), (4, 'CS'), (2,'is'), (3, 'is')] instead, right?

Comment: no,  its ('is', 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

test_list = [(1, 'the'), (1, 'is'), (2, 'best'), (3, 'for'),(1, 'is'), (4, 'CS'), (2,'is'), ('is',3)]

result = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in test_list:
    result[k].add(v)
    result[v].add(k)

print(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
{1: {'is', 'the'}, 'the': {1}, 'is': {1, 2, 3}, 2: {'is', 'best'}, 'best': {2}, 3: {'for', 'is'}, 'for': {3}, 4: {'CS'}, 'CS': {4}}
```

If you can't use `defaultdict`, you just need to replace it with the equivalent with normal `dict` with an added if-statement:

```
result = dict()
...
    if k not in result:
        result[k] = set()
    result[k].add(v)
    if v not in result:
        result[v] = set()
    result[v].add(k)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way to do it? i am restricted not to use defaultdict, sorry for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: I have tried if other way but its not working like deafultdict

test_list.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
res = dict((k, [v[1] for v in itr]) for k, itr in groupby( 
                                test_list, itemgetter(0))) 
test_list.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
res.update(dict((k, [v[0] for v in itr]) for k, itr in groupby( 
                                test_list, itemgetter(1))) )

Comment: Edited with normal dict option